# is it possible to check if pdf is password protected using ghostscript?

Tags: ghostscript

is it possible to check if pdf is password protected using ghostscript?
what would be the command? 
I know you can strip pdf password using ghostscript, 
but all I want to do is just checking if PDF is password protected or security enabled.

Comment: Having started a bounty, I would also like to know whether it is possible to detect password-protected PDFs with other tools.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`checkuserpasswdPDF.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

GS=~/gs/bin/gs
output=`$GS -dBATCH -sNODISPLAY "$1" 2>&1`
gsexit=$?

if [ "$gsexit" == "0" ]; then
  echo "Not user-password protected"
  exit 0;
else
  found=`echo "$output" |grep -o "This file requires a password"`
  if [ -z "$found" ]; then
    echo "Failed to invoke gs" 
    exit $gsexit
  else
    echo "Protected"
    exit 0;
  fi  
fi
```

Checks for user-password protected PDFs: `checkuserpasswdPDF.sh test.pdf`.

GS disregards owner-passwords (see [this](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/usr/dst/www/Adobe/Gallery/Keating/)).

Comment: humm this looks promising, I will give this a try

Comment: This command takes much time for larger pdf and increases server load

Answer (score 3):

With `pdftk` it is possible to detect a user password or owner password by just trying to do a `dump_data` operation.

```
 protected=0
 pdftk "input.pdf" dump_data output /dev/null dont_ask || protected=1
```

The problem here is that you don't know what the password prevents: reading, extracting data, modifying...?

Comment: i tried something similar, but it was limiting and pdftk wasn't always giving me correct result.

Answer (score 3):

Using a bat file, you can do a little workaround by searching for "Encrypt" in the pdfs. Its quiet fast to search through many files.

```
Findstr /M /I "Encrypt" *.pdf
```

This will return all filenames that are secured (since "Encrypt" will be written in the file as dos reads it)

Maybe this is something someone can use.
I use:
`for /f %%a in ('Findstr /M /I "Encrypt" *.pdf') do move %%a c:\tempfiles\` 
 to move all secured pdf's to c:\tempfiles. From there I use ghostscript to remove the security, and move it back to original folder.

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't distinguish between owner password protection and user password protection. This test shows if it has _any_ password protection

Answer (score 2):

You can test using `pdfinfo`

```
pdfinfo $filename &>/dev/null;
if [[ $? -eq 1 ]] ; then
   echo "File can not be opened for reading"
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

The answer of @Benoit gives ugly errors on console, but works.

So I would put this to an oneliner with suppression of error output:

```
protected=0 && pdftk "input.pdf" dump_data output /dev/null dont_ask 2>/dev/null || protected=1
```