# How to find password protected pdf-files in a directory?

Tags: pdf, command-line

In a windows directory I have about 100 pdf-files, some are password protected, some are not. Is there an easy way (in the command-line or maybe with a freeware tool) to find the ones which are password protected without opening each of them in a pdf-reader?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Windows, you can use the [iTextSharp](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/releases) library to accomplish this.

First, extract itextsharp.dll, which is inside the itextsharp-dll-core archive.

Then, use the following PowerShell script:

```
Add-Type -Path .\itextsharp.dll

Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |
ForEach-Object {
    $filename = $_.Name
    Try {
        $pdf = New-Object iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($_.FullName)
        If ($pdf.IsEncrypted()) {
            $filename
        }
    }
    Catch {
        $filename
    }
}
```

The output will be the name of each PDF which is secured or encrypted.

Comment: The script runs fine when there are no password protected files in the directory and I get the following error if there is one:
`New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Bad user password"
At line:4 char:22
+     $pdf = New-Object <<<<  iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader($_.FullName)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand`

Comment: I updated the script to fix this issue. Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the script of [is it possible to check if pdf is password protected using ghostscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4396941/150978) and extend it to iterate over a bunch of files and eg. move all non-password protected files into a subdirectory.