# Identify if a PDF is read-only or password protected in PHP

Tags: php, symfony, pdf

I'm currently working on a PHP project where you can upload (through a simple file_get_contents) and edit a PDF.
My current goal is to detect if the uploaded PDF is protected in any way (read only, encrypted, password protected) so I can reject it during the upload process.

I'm using TCPDI, but open to other suggestions (including parsing the whole string). I've also found a thread about using Ghostscript, but it seems that option isn't reliable :

[is it possible to check if pdf is password protected using ghostscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4039659/is-it-possible-to-check-if-pdf-is-password-protected-using-ghostscript)

Regards,

Comment: Are you searching for an open-source/free solution or would a [paid one](https://manuals.setasign.com/setapdf-core-manual/standard-encryption/#index-4) work for you too?

Comment: I would prefer a free solution, if possible :)